# htaccess - redirect if rule doesn't exists

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to ask - is there a way to auto redirect with httacces conditions when rewrite rule doesn't exists?

For example.

I have the following rules:

```
 RewriteRule ^/index/$ index.php
 RewriteRule ^/error-404/$ 404.php
 ErrorDocument 404 /error-404/
```

When someone will try to access adress like index/something-added-by-user/ he will see 404 page, but url will be still "index/something-added-by-user/". Is there a way to automatically redirect from that url typed by user to url "error-404/"? So when he type url like above, he will see 404 page with 404 page url.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using this rule:

```
# not a real dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# not a real file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# not a real link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
# redirect it to 404.php
RewriteRule ^ /404.php [R,L]
```

Though keep in mind that browser will not get 200 status instead of 404.